# Android App closes properly but won't open again

Tags: android

I am working on an app that i require it closes when the user press the close button, I managed to make it work by using a finish() function when the starter activity is called from another one instead of starting. However when i try to open the app again it's closes automatically.

LoginActivity (App where the close button is located):

```
public static final String closeKey = "closeKey";
//I cut off the entire onCreate function to show only the close app code
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.putExtra(closeKey,"closeApp");
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

As you can see what i do is that i send an extra elemente on the intent, this will indicate to my starter activity that i want the app to close.

LoadingActivity (Starter App):

```
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras == null){
        executeAnim();
    }else{
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);
        finish();
    }
```

The LoadingActivity checks if there is any extras on the intent, if there is not it will trigger the loading animation and go to the LoadingActivity, and if there is an extra element it will close the activity because it's indicating that you want to close it.

Comment: Have you tried sticking a `Log.d` in there to see what `extras` ends up being? Setting a breakpoint on `if(extras==null)` will let you see the contents of that variable as well. I'm betting that's where your problem is.

Comment: Chances are the activity still lives and is recreated when you launch app again, which checks the extras, sees the 'close' and kills again

Comment: I made it work, had to add a few validations but now it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work, had to add a few validations to the if/else in the LoadingActivity:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras == null){
        executeAnim();
    }else if (extras.getString(LoginActivity.closeKey) == null){
        executeAnim();
    }else if (extras.getString(LoginActivity.closeKey) ==  ""){
        executeAnim();
    }else {
        try{
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(0);
            finish();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```